# Q: lighttpd uses 2GB ram while idle for private page

Tags: php-fpm, lighttpd, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running a server with lighttpd installed. It runs php5-fpm and servering an owncloud server.

- Ubuntu Server 14.04
- lighttpd/1.4.33 (ssl) (Jan 28 2014 17:26:04) - a light and fast webserver
- PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Oct 29 2014 11:59:19)

> ```
> server.modules = (
>         "mod_access",
>         "mod_alias",
>         "mod_compress",
>         "mod_redirect"
> )
>
> server.document-root        = "/var/www"
> server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
> server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
> server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
> server.username             = "www-data"
> server.groupname            = "www-data"
> server.port                 = 80
>
>
> index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
> url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
> static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )
>
> compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
> compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )
>
> # default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
> ## Use ipv6 if available
> #include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
> include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
> include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"
> ```

After some time the memory usage looks like this:

[image]

Anyone has an idea how to fix this without need of a restart everytime?

Comment: Seems related to this: [lighttpd bug #1283](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/1283).

Can you use Nginx instead?

Comment: Don't send large files from php, either use static files directly or the `X-sendfile` header.